# Good way to feed input data of different sizes into neural network? (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

My data looks like this. They are floats and they are in a big numpy array [700000,3]. There are no empty fields.

```
Label   | Values1   | Values2
1.      | 0.01      | 0.01
1.      | ...       | ...
1.      |
2.      |
2.      |
3.      |
...
```

The idea is to feed in the set of values1 and values2 and have it identify the label using classification.

But I don't want to feed the data row by row, but input all values1/2 that belong to label 1 as a set (e.g. inputting the first 3 rows is supposed to return [1,0,...], inputting the next 2 rows as a set [0,1,...])

Is there a non-complex way of feeding the data in this way? (i.e. feed batch where column label equals 1)

I am currently sorting the data and thinking about using pointers to the start and having loops which check if the next row is equal to the current to find a pointer to the end of the set and get the number of rows of that batch. But this more or less prevents randomizing input order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your data in a numpy array (let's call it `data`, you can use

```
single_digit = data[(data[:,0] == 1.)][: , 1:]
```

which will compare the zeroth element of each row with the digit (`1.` in this case) and select only the rows having the label `1.`. From these rows, it takes the first and second element, i.e. Values1 and Values2. A working example is below. You can use a for loop to iterate over all labels contained in the data set and construct a numpy array for each label with

```
single_digit = data[(data[:,0] == label_of_this_iteration)][: , 1:]
```

and then feed these arrays to the network. Within TensorFlow you can easily feed batches of different length, if you do not specify the first dimension of the corresponding placeholders.

```
import numpy as np
# Generate some data with three columns (label, Values1, Values2)
n = 20
ints = np.random.randint(1,6,(n, 1))
dous = np.random.uniform(size=(n,2))
data = np.hstack((ints, dous))
print(data)

# Extract the second and third columns of all rows having the label 1.0
ones = data[(data[:,0] == 1.)][: , 1:]
print(ones)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally use TFRecords format.

> This approach makes it easier to mix and match data sets and network architectures

Here is a link for detail on what this json like structure looks like [example.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto)